# bash reading string with spaces as parameter

Tags: string, bash, parameters, space

I found on a forum how to solve when a function is called with more parameters and each as string with spaces, but how to read string with spaces from input, I mean when somebody calls my script.

In this case, user should send two txt files addresses. So, I know the suffix, but he could also send files that haven't got that suffix. So, is there any way how to read the two file addresses?

Answer (score 1):

The script arguments are kept in so called "positional parameters". For example, if the script is called as

```
script.sh /path/to/1.txt 2.csv
```

`$1` will contain the first file path and `$2` the second one.

Comment: Yea, but this didn't work while there was a space in a pathline - script.sh /path to/new folder/a.txt /new folder/fileWithoutSuffix, even when tried qouting :(

Comment: You have to quote the variables as well, i.e. `script.sh '/path to/1.txt' '2.csv'`, and `"$1"` and `"$2"`.